# PHP MySQL fails when page is viewed remotely

Tags: php, networking, mysql

I have two servers on my local network - one a web frontend and the other a MySQL backend. I have a PHP script that looks like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
echo "Connecting...\n";
$link = mysql_connect("192.168.1.15", "-----", "-----") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Communicating with the server...";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO .....
//More code down here...
?>
```

This script is called on my web frontend to connect to the backend server. When this script is accessed from the local network (i.e. when I open the page by going to http://192.168.1.14), the script outputs

```
Connecting...
Communicating with the server...
```

and a row is added to the database, as it should. However when I connect remotely (i.e. going to http://myDomainName.com/mysql_insert_script.php) from a connection not on the local network, all I see is:

```
Connecting...
```

No error messages follow, the script just cuts off, and no data is added to the database. When I place a second, 'proxy' script on the server that simply requires() the above script and then I access the proxy remotely, everything works fine. Below is the proxy script, so you can get a better idea of what works and what does not:

```
<?php
//this script makes it appear that the mysql_script is being viewed from the local network
//I exist on the web frontend at 192.168.1.14
require("http://192.168.1.15/mysql_insert_script.php");
?>
```

I am sorry if I can't provide any more information, but I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Chris

P.S. - I have verified that the mysql server is accessible from external hosts on the local network, but I have a firewall that prevents connections from outside my network. I don't think this would matter, however, as the MySQL server and the PHP script connecting to it are both run on the local net.

Comment: Does anything get added to the error_log when you run it without the require?

Comment: Did you try `require("http://myDomainName.com/mysql_insert_script.php");`  on your proxy ?

Comment: Make sure display_errors or error_log/log_errors are enabled in your php.ini so that any MySQL connection errors are recorded.

Comment: Swap error_reporting(-1); with error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: is the web front-end ahead of your firewall? or are you adding external exceptions/port forwarding? Try having it fopen a file on the backend server and see if it can at least get to it. If it can, it's likely a port issue. Next step is to try using an exec and run a telnet and redirect output to the web. If you see it trying to connect, something most likely bigger is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got wrong server name